# WooCommerce Bookings: hourly starting times

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

**Remark:**
I'm posting my question here, hoping for a little more feedback than on the main support site of WooThemes (where there seems no response). I'm now trying to fix this issue myself, so I can launch my site, because I highly doubt my [Bug Report / Suggestion](http://ideas.woothemes.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/6097737-flexible-start-time-for-bookings-with-fixed-block) on the WooThemes site will get enough attention (until it maybe attracts more votes).

**Issue:**
For my forthcoming website, I'm using the [WooCommerce Bookings](http://woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/) plugin. It works pretty neat, but it doesn't allow my clients to FREELY (rounded by the hour) select the starting time of a fixed-length session. At the moment, the length of a booking slot with "fixed blocks" (i.e. 1/2/3 hours) will enforce specific times you can select a booking.

**Example:** 
A client can book sessions with a fixed duration of 3 hours. You can easily set this up in WC Bookings (called "fixed blocks"):

[image: screenshot from WC Bookings]

The start time of a session is flexible, so I want them to pick it themselves. However, WC Bookings will now only display the times: 0:00, 3:00, 6:00 etc. However, I'd like **1:00, 2:00, 4:00, 5:00 also be available** (as long as they don't conflict with another active booking, obviously).

[image: Screenshot from shop front-end]

Currently, the only way to show all hours is to set the actual duration of the session to 1 hour, which isn't an option because it confuses all subsequent communication about the booking – let alone messes up the whole booking system itself.

Comment: sadly... no, nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I am just trying the bookings extension out and I wish they had this option as well. I think I may have found a work around though.

I set the booking duration to customer defined blocks of of how often I'd like the time slots available. (seemingly 1 hour in your case)

Then set the minimum and maximum duration both to the fixed booking length. (3 hours for you)

This displays a drop down on the site for the customers to select duration. We don't want that there, and its kind of useless since we limited them to one choice anyway.  However, we can hide that by using the css code:

```
p.wc_bookings_field_duration{
  display: none;
}
```

Again, I'm just messing around with this and have not fully tested it, but at this point it seems like a viable workaround to me. Hope it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, tony. I'm afraid i can't test it out because I stopped using the WooCommerce Bookings plugin – there were too many unresolved issues for my purpose. I do hope this helps someone else: please comment if so :)

Comment: Yeah that works. Its not the best plugin but I think its getting there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an 3 years later, and the extensions has evolved since.
I think we should use resouces for this case, the availability is then calculated for resources, not for bookable product.
Hope this would help someone else.